# Selectively turn off external monitors

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop running Windows 10. 4 external monitors are connected through 2 hubs.

Each monitor extends my desktop. Application windows are located on every monitor.

I already have a script to turn off the monitor displays

> nircmd monitor off

I now need to turn off all monitors BUT one, while keeping the windows locations. I need complete darkness around one single monitor temporarily.

Right now I have to manually switch off the screens. It works for old NEC screens. But not for the new Ilyama because Windows 10 thinks i disconnected the screen.

Can you send commands to external monitors to switch off/on their back lights?